# How to configure a domain name with a virtual host in Webmin?

Tags: linux, debian, ovh, webmin

I'm setting up my raspberry pi for shared hosting. My aim is to host more websites by purchasing domain names through providers such as ovh.com or register.com
I am using webmin to create the web servers, I have installed the modules: Apache Web Server, DNS Bind Server. My problem is that mine is a home hosting so I have only one public ip address, how do I make sure to use the same shared ip address with multiple domain names? it's possible to do it?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeflh.png)

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply. Some related topics may be asked on Webmasters

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are called virtual hosts in Apache lingo. See the Apache documentation:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Basically you'll define at least a Virtual Host name and a folder from which to serve its web pages for each website you wish to host.

Something like:

```
<VirtualHost <your IP>:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/www/docs/host.example.com"
  ServerName host.example.com
  ErrorLog "logs/host.example.com-error_log"
  TransferLog "logs/host.example.com-access_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Repeated for each hostname for which you want your server to serve queries.

As for the Webmin Apache module, [it has a "Virtual Host" section.](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Apache_Webserver#Creating_a_new_virtual_host)

Notice that in your case, your public (internet facing) IP address may not be fixed; so you may need to use a dynamic DNS system.
Also, generally you'll need to forward the proper ports from your router to your server (generally 80 and 443 for TLS).

Comment: I've done all of this but how should I set up my domain name?
I created an A record from the domain name provider pointing to the public address, but doing so in both domains example1.it and example2.org point to the same page and not their folders

Comment: @antoniodilorenzo show your Apache configuration file. Remember that there are two different configurations for http and https, too.